# Can you change Outlook desktop notifications to metro style in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, microsoft-outlook, modern-ui

There is a major difference in the Windows 7 and Windows 8 Outlook desktop alerts (see below).  I was wondering if it was possible to make it so the desktop notifications seen in Windows 8 could be emulated in Windows 7 (and please don't tell me to upgrade OS!)

[image: Windows 8 notification]

[image: Windows 7 Notification]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not possible in Windows 7. The Picture of Windows 8 shows the new [Toast notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802768) which was added in Windows 8 first.