# Can I make Outlook toast notifications smaller in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, notifications

I disabled Windows 10 notifications originally, but I find that I miss the Outlook 'new mail' notifications that I used back when I ran Windows 7, so I have re-enabled notifications for Outlook only. However, the Windows 10 notifications are gargantuan compared to Windows 7 notifications (I'm assuming this is program-agnostic, not specific to Outlook, but maybe I'm wrong):

Windows 10 notification:

[image: Windows 10 notification]

I'd much rather have the notification be closer to the size of the red box outlined above, similar to how big the Windows 7 notifications were:

[image: Windows 7 notification - borrowed from https://superuser.com/q/737529]

Alternatively, can I at least hide the 'action row' (the "Delete", "Flag", and "Dismiss" actions) from the notification, somehow? I don't ever use the flag functionality of Outlook, rarely want to delete something without reading the full e-mail, and think two buttons to dismiss the notification is rather stupid/poor UI design.

- I've checked in Windows 10 Settings in Notifications & Actions section, but that only turns them off/on
- I've checked the Ease of Access section, but that only lets me set the duration of the notification.
- I've checked in Outlook's Settings in the Mail section, but that is only a full toggle.
- I've even checked in the Outlook-specific Notification settings view, but that doesn't let me resize the notification window either... just shows more toggles between binary or trinary states.

Is this customization possible somehow? I'm open to solutions that include Outlook settings changes, Windows Settings changes, Registry edits, PowerShell scripts, or even 3rd party utilities like Start10 (which I use, but doesn't seem to cover the notification aspect of the Windows 10 start menu/task bar).

I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise version 21H2 and Outlook v2202 from Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise, if that matters.

Comment: Notifications on Windows 7 were handled entirely by the application, while on Windows 10, notifications are handled by Windows itself.  You will likely find that Outlook no longer supports the legacy notifications on Windows 10.  This will be especially true since you are using Office 2022 which to my knowledge does NOT support Windows 7. *You can try running Outlook in (Windows 7) compatibility mode.*

Comment: @Ramhound The Outlook application doesn't seem to provide a Compatibility tab in the Properties window... at least not for this version of Outlook. We have Windows Troubleshooting wizard disabled in our environment due to a CVE vuln from earlier this year; could that be the cause of that?

Comment: You have to go to the executable itself to use the Compatability Mode, and that might not even work, since you are working with an version of Outlook which does not even support Windows 7.  I found an article that setting the Compatibility Mode, will force Outlook to display it's own notifications, if it works with Outlook 2022 or Office 365 is something I cannot determined as the article is 2 years old.

Comment: @Ramhound I did check the actual .exe file (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE`), not just a shortcut. Can you link to this article, by any chance?

Comment: You should be able to find it by searching for "legacy outlook notifications office 2022", if the compatibility mode is missing on the executable, it means the work around cannot be used on Office 365 nor Office 2022

Comment: I'm assuming it's this one, which was my top result for that query: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-old-style-outlook-notifications-in-windows-10/ but it's hard to say for sure without you confirming or just providing the link yourself.

Comment: Yes; That's the article

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently possible via the Windows Compatibility Troubleshooter per a 2020 [TechRepublic article](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-old-style-outlook-notifications-in-windows-10/) I found ([hinted at](https://superuser.com/questions/1751971/can-i-make-outlook-toast-notifications-smaller-in-windows-10#comment2719743_1751971) and eventually [confirmed by Ramhound](https://superuser.com/questions/1751971/can-i-make-outlook-toast-notifications-smaller-in-windows-10#comment2719821_1751971) in the comments as well), titled *How to enable old-style Outlook notifications in Windows 10* by Mark W. Kaelin.

The relevant steps are:

1. Navigate to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\<CurrentOfficeVersion>\` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\<CurrentOfficeVersion>\`
2. Right-click OUTLOOK.EXE and select "Troubleshoot Compatibility"
3. Choose the "Troubleshoot program" option from the Program Compatibility Troubleshooter
4. Select "The program worked in earlier versions of Windows but won't install or run now" from the next page and then select "Next"
5. Select "Windows 7" from the list of Operating Systems and then select "Next"
6. Test the application (a required step for the Troubleshooter)
7. Select "Yes, save these settings for this program"

I say "*apparently* possible" because in my environment the Program Compatibility Troubleshooter is disabled via group policy due to a CVE, so I am unable to confirm this works, personally.